# Applying styles to a listitem inside a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Good day.

I would like to know if it is possible to apply styles to a listitem
 that is nested in a div with javascript. On my page there is already alot of divs with listitems but i only want to apply a style to that specific listitems.

The only reason i want to apply styles to the listitem using javascrip is because there is viewing issues with IE 7 that doesnt want to accept css styles inside the div.

My HTML is:

```
<ol>    
   <li>
      GENERAL PRINCIPLES UNDERLYING THE REPRESENTIVE COUNCIL OF LEARNERS
      <div id = "divv">
         <ol>
            <li>....</li>
            <li>....</li>
            <li>....</li>
            <li>....</li>
            <li>....</li>
         </ol>
      </div>
    </li>
<ol>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you can't style the sub list with something like "#divv ol li" as the CSS selector?

Comment: get the div element by its id and do the DOM traversal , search google for DOM traversal with javascript, you ll find lot of good articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a JSFiddle that demonstrate CSS styling of the inner list

http://jsfiddle.net/adrianjmartin/9V8tR

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you can and it should work on IE7 too because its something IE has always been supporting, eg;

```
#divv ol li{your style properties here}
```

should work on all browsers. The only scenario wherein this wouldn't work is if you have cancelled "ol li" styling with '!important' somewhere else in your css.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using a combination of getElementById and getElementsByTagName and then running a loop on the items found and adding the css style using javascript.
Here s a jsfiddle for the same: http://jsfiddle.net/saganbyte/m65CF/1/

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is grab the div with an ID and from there traverse the DOM until you get to the list you want. Then just use the list style object to inject the style you want.

Also I suspect that if you can't do it from CSS there is more problem into it, as well structured CSS can always be apply (unless unsupported of course)

Here is a little fiddle with the test markup you provided, it grab the div, find the OL inside it and then add a border to it.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dj5gH/1/

```
var div = document.getElementById('divv'),
    found = false,
    elem = div.firstChild;

while (!found) {

    if (elem.nodeType == 1) {
        elem.style.border = '2px solid red';
        found = true;
    }
    else elem = elem.nextSibling;
};​
```